# How to make a PWA Add to Screen button to work on Safari and Android browser?

Tags: javascript, android, safari, progressive-web-apps

I;m trying to implement a pwa application on a small site and i need to addToHomeScreen button. It works fine on chrome mobile and desktop but not on native Android browser or Safari.

The code is this:

```js
window.onload = () => {
  'use strict';

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
             .register('/sw.js');
  }
}


let installPromptEvent;
btnInstall=document.querySelector(".add-button");
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (event) => {
  console.log("before");
  // Prevent Chrome <= 67 from automatically showing the prompt
  event.preventDefault();
  // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
  installPromptEvent = event;
  // Update the install UI to notify the user app can be installed
  document.querySelector('.add-button').style.display= "block";
});
btnInstall.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // Update the install UI to remove the install button
  document.querySelector('.add-button').style.display= "none";
  // Show the modal add to home screen dialog
  //installPromptEvent.prompt();

  if (installPromptEvent) {

    installPromptEvent.prompt();
  
    installPromptEvent.userChoice.then((choice) => {
      if (choice.outcome === 'accepted') {
        console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
      } else {
        console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
      }
      // Clear the saved prompt since it can't be used again
      installPromptEvent = null;
    }); 
  }
```

```html
<button class="add-button">Instaleaza aplicatia</button>
```

Can anyone to help me?

Thanks

Comment: beforeinstallprompt is not supported by safari https://caniuse.com/?search=beforeinstallprompt

Comment: and on firefox? This must work? Thanks